# Angular 17 Animation - Synch both sides on slide left/right

Tags: css, angular, angular-animations

I'm trying to add an animation to Angular 17 application but it is not working as expected.

Basically there are two `divs`, side by side and left side is hidden by `*ngIf` when a button is pressed. Animation from left side works as expected but right `div` does not follow, it is resized only when animation completes.

Here is the sample code: https://stackblitz-starters-uwgcaa.stackblitz.io

How do I make animation work in both sides?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change the animation from `translateX` to `margin-left`, looked up the CSS tutorials and found the solution!

```
import {
  animate,
  group,
  query,
  style,
  transition,
  trigger,
} from '@angular/animations';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  provideAnimations,
} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menu" *ngIf="showMenu" [@slideInOut]="showMenu">Menu</div>
      <div class="content">Content<button (click)="toggleMenu()">Teste</button></div>
    </div>
  `,
  animations: [
    trigger('slideInOut', [
      transition(':enter', [
        style({ marginLeft: '-100%' }),
        animate('200ms', style({ marginLeft: '0px' })),
      ]),
      transition(':leave', [
        animate('200ms', style({ marginLeft: '-100%' })),
      ]),
    ]),
  ],
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
  showMenu = true;

  toggleMenu() {
    this.showMenu = !this.showMenu;
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App, { providers: [provideAnimations()] });
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-ftpymt?file=src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fglobal_styles.css)

---

#### References

1. [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qo6dx3w4/1/)
2. [article](https://blog.pagesd.info/2020/06/02/sidebar-css-animation/)

Comment: Hey @Naren Murali, there is weird behavior if I set a custom width of one side, it seems animation goes to back and returns to correct position. Please see updated code here: https://stackblitz-starters-eo2ra5.stackblitz.io

Comment: Changing delay we can see clearly it goes to left and then returns to correct position. What is happening? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @EmilioNumazaki I think its due to use of `%` and `em` together, I set both to same units and it got fixed! [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-fvuvfq?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: @EmilioNumazaki You're welcome! have a great year ahead!